# Choosing list from matrix that maximizes a fitness function

Tags: algorithm

I'm developing a music application, and I'm running into trouble with an algorithm. Here is a toy version of the problem. Let's say we have `n` cities that we want to visit, in a certain order. What we are given is a list of possible cities for each 'step':

`{{"London","Glasgow"},{"Munich","London"},{"Glasgow","Munich","London"}}`

We have to simplify this down to a list of cities in order by picking a city from each of these sub-lists. We are also given a list of distances from each city to each other:

`{{"London"->"Glasgow,100},{"London"->"Munich",400},{"Munich"->"London",300},...}`

Notice that this list isn't symmetric - London to Munich can be different from Munich to London (something something efficiency of german planes). Also assume that the distance from any city to itself is 0. We want to pick the list with the least overall distance.

The list does not have to hit every city, it can hit the same city multiple times. For the example above, the most efficient solution would be 
`{London, London, London}`.

Up to now, I've been using a greedy algorithm, but that won't always give the best result. The only other option I've considered (other than brute force) is a genetic algorithm, but that isn't ever guaranteed to give the optimal solution either.

What's the most efficient algorithm to accomplish this?

Comment: That looks like a [TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: @Cid I thought so too, but a big difference is this doesn't have to visit every city, can visit the same city multiple times and multiple times in a row, and has a list of options rather than just a list of cities and distances. So I'm not sure how a TSP algorithm could adapted.

Comment: In TSP problem, we need visit every city inside, but here, if we create pseudo start city  and end city, we got a shortest path problem. Now let's consider the problem scale....

Comment: I'm unclear on whether you have a list of possible next cities for each *city* or for each *time step*.  Anyway, if the list does not have to hit every city then the optimal solution is an empty list.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I state in the spec that we must pick a city from each of our options.

Comment: @HolaYang Good thinking. Scale is small, always around 10-20 steps, 7 cities, and 3 options per step.

Comment: @TreFox: Ah, so your initial data structure means that at time 1, you need to pick one of London or Glasgow, and at time 2 you need to pick one of Munich or London, etc.?  This wasn't clear to me.  Anyway, in that case HolaYang's shortest-path approach is the way to go -- it will efficiently find an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify the problem in such a way.

Split the city occurred multiple times into different cities, and construct a hierarchical graph. Add two pseudo cities as start and end, then it becomes a shortest path problem.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) for more info about shortest path problem.